# Fluentd not getting the correct docker container name after rancher upgrade

Tags: docker, elastic-stack, fluentd, rancher

Imagine a set of containers specified by a docker compose file. These containers run with the help of rancher. Containers are setup to use the fluentd logging driver. The logging driver sends messages to elastic search and we use Kabana to view our logs.

This setup is working fine until we perform a rancher upgrade. After the rancher upgrade the container name gets set to the UUID value of the container. This makes debugging hard as not all of the debugging messages work with the container name filter as the UUID will always be different.

If the stack is deleted from rancher and then redeployed the original name of the container is restored and logging resumes normally. Why does the container name get reported as the UUID value after a rancher upgrade? How can we ensure that the container name is always set correctly in our logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue relates to old containers still existing so rancher cannot give the new containers the same name as this conflicts.

The rancher team have an open issue here - https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/4993